# Accessing a typescript variable inside ngif statement in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have a variable in ts. I wanna access it inside ngif.

TS:

```
  public data:string
```

HTML:

```
  <td> 
      <div *ngIf="data === 'BALL' ; else noplay" >{{ play}}</div>
      <ng-template #noplay> {{gotohome}} 
     </ng-template>
  </td>
```

What I am doing is that if the variable data has value "BALL" I will display a value in table using string interpolation and if condition is not met a different value will be shown. I am findinfg it difficult to access the data variable from typescript

A sample stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c6zyqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty here? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Seems like the variable `data` is not getting initialized properly. `*ngIf` syntax seems to be correct. Could you please provide more details or a stackblitz with the same scenario?

Comment: I have added the stackblitz link @JinsThomasShaji

Comment: try add this =>`constructor() {
    this.get();
  }`

Comment: I think you declare the variable but not call it, that's why it's not showing.

Comment: I found out my mistake and got answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using method `get()` for assigning value to variable `data`. But that method is not invoked anywhere. That's causing the issue.

I've updated stackblitz by initializing value with declaration ad it works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g5a852?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

If you want to use getter, refer the below stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wn8ccz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

The getter is defined incorrectly, use the following syntax:

```
  _data;

  get data() {
    return this._data = "BALL";
  }
```